# Delete the row as we click the checkbox

Tags: android, checkbox

I have a strange requirement. I have multiple rows having checkbox each. Now i need to delete the row as soon as the check box is checked. I have done this so far but its not working.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      CheckBox checkbox = new CheckBox(this);
       checkbox.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

          @Override
          public void onClick(View v) { 

     delete();
          }
        });

}
```

Thanks In Advance ...

Comment: what you use to display Rows ListView?

Comment: care to elaborate delete() a little more? and checkbox? the checkbox appears to be in an activity. i thought we are talking about a listview. im confused

Comment: You code is more strange than requirement...You are registering listener which is technically nothing...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a good design. The user does not expect a checkbox to delete an item from the list. However, if you really want to do it, use an `OnCheckedChangeListener`:

```
checkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

    public void onCheckedChange(CompoundButton checkbox, boolean checked) {
        delete();
    }

}
```